# ios cell background color must change

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, background-color

in my ios app, i have a view with several cells called PersonalDetailTVC. After selecting a value on another view the app returns to PersonalDetailTVC, and I want that the background color of certain cell changes depending on the new value, but the colour only changes when I return to the view again. Can you help me, please?

```
#import "PersonDetailTVC.h"

@implementation PersonDetailTVC
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize person = _person;
@synthesize selectedRole;
@synthesize personFirstnameTextField = _personFirstnameTextField;
@synthesize personSurnameTextField = _personSurnameTextField;
@synthesize personRoleTableViewCell = _personRoleTableViewCell;
@synthesize groupColorTableViewCell = _groupColorTableViewCell;



- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    NSLog(@"Setting the value of fields in this static table to that of the passed Person");
    //self.personNameTextField.text = self.person.name;
    self.personFirstnameTextField.text = self.person.firstname;
    self.personSurnameTextField.text = self.person.surname;
    self.personRoleTableViewCell.textLabel.text = self.person.inRole.name;
    self.groupColorTableViewCell.textLabel.text = self.person.hasColor.color;
    self.selectedRole = self.person.inRole; // ensure null role doesn't get saved.

    if ([self.person.hasColor.color isEqual:@"Grey"]){
        self.groupColorTableViewCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [tgr setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    //[self setPersonNameTextField:nil];
    [self setPersonFirstnameTextField:nil];
    [self setPersonSurnameTextField:nil];
    [self setPersonRoleTableViewCell:nil];
     [self setGroupColorTableViewCell:nil];

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Telling the PersonDetailTVC Delegate that Save was tapped on the PersonDetailTVC");

    self.person.firstname = self.personFirstnameTextField.text; // Set Firstname
    self.person.surname = self.personSurnameTextField.text; // Set Surname
    [self.person setInRole:self.selectedRole];
    [self.person setHasColor:self.selectedRole];// Set Relationship!!!
    [self.person.managedObjectContext save:nil];  // write to database
    [self.delegate theSaveButtonOnThePersonDetailTVCWasTapped:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender  // !
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Person Role Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonDetailTVC as a delegate of PersonRoleTVC");
        PersonRoleTVC *personRoleTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personRoleTVC.delegate = self;
        personRoleTVC.selectedPerson = self.person;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Unidentified Segue Attempted!");
    }
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
}

- (void)roleWasSelectedOnPersonRoleTVC:(PersonRoleTVC *)controller 
{
    self.personRoleTableViewCell.textLabel.text = controller.selectedRole.name;
    self.groupColorTableViewCell.textLabel.text = controller.selectedRole.color;
    self.selectedRole = controller.selectedRole;




    NSLog(@"PersonDetailTVC reports that the %@ role was selected on the PersonRoleTVC", controller.selectedRole.name);
    [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


@end
```

Comment: Have you tried reloading the cell [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; it would be good if you post code for custom cell

Comment: thank you Vishal, but there is no tableview, it is only a TableViewCell, how could I reload it? This is the code used to change the background colour, it is inside the viewDidLoad method:if ([self.person.hasColor.color isEqual:@"Grey"]){
        self.groupColorTableViewCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    }

Comment: How you are using tableviewcell then, directly adding to view ?

Comment: Yes...but I could change it for textfield, would it be better?

Comment: Yes its not recommended to use tableviewcell without TableviewController

Comment: @VishalKardode I'd like to see a reference to your statement - I've used them alone before no problems. Also I cannot figure out what the O.P. Is asking - please better comment the above code as to what is not working.

Comment: It's not a problem to use `UITableViewCell` without a table view.  `UITableViewCell` is derived from `UIView` and can be used as any other `UIView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see, you're not changing a color anywhere in the provided code. While reading the code, i noticed a few things, so i thought i share it with you, maybe it helps:

---

If I understand correctly you are using a `UITableViewCell` without a `UITableView`. This is actually not a problem as `UITableViewCell` derives from `UIView`, but the cell will not have the behaviour of a `UITableViewCell` (because this is usually controlled by a `UITableView`). When adding a `UITableViewCell` manually as a subview, the cell will have the default behaviour of a `UIView`.

---

In your `save:` method I see the following 2 lines:

```
[self.person setInRole:self.selectedRole];
[self.person setHasColor:self.selectedRole];// Set Relationship!!!
```

Are you intentionally passing `self.selectedRole` to a property `hasColor` (or `setHasColor:` method)? Since I don't know the types of these objects this might be OK, but looks like you should set a color there.

---

In the `roleWasSelectedOnPersonRoleTVC:` method your are currently setting the text property twice:

```
self.personRoleTableViewCell.textLabel.text = controller.selectedRole.name;
self.groupColorTableViewCell.textLabel.text = controller.selectedRole.color;
```

Shouldn't that last line be something like this?

```
self.groupColorTableViewCell.textLabel.textColor = controller.selectedRole.color;
```

Comment: Thank you all. Leijonien, you are right. I have add following code to the roleWasSelectedOnPersonRoleTVC:    self.groupColorTextField.text = controller.selectedRole.color;
    
    
    if ([controller.selectedRole.color isEqual:@"Black"])
    {
        self.groupColorTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        self.groupColorTextField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0 ];
    }//and also a if clause for each of the ten colors I have defined. Thank you